# Задача с оценкой О(n).Посчитать сумму в матрицах m на m,которые содержит матрица n на n

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы, структуры-данных

Дана квадратная таблица **a[1..n][1..n]** и число **m<=n**. Для каждого квадрата размера m на m  в  этой  таблице  вычислить сумму  стоящих в нем чисел. Общее число действий должно быть порядка **n*n**.

Найти число операций и вывести его на экран.

Так же нашел в интернете указание:
Сначала для каждого горизонтального прямоугольника размером m на 1 вычисляем сумму стоящих в нем чисел. (При сдвиге такого прямоугольника по горизонтали на 1 нужно добавить одно число и одно вычесть.) Затем, используя эти суммы, вычисляем суммы в квадратах. (При сдвиге квадрата по вертикали добавляется полоска, а другая полоска убавляется).

Пытался написать программу,но никак не могу уложиться в n*n действий.Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: продемонстрируйте что у вас получилось

Comment: Не надо писать суммы для квадратов 2x2 и далее. За N^2 считаются суммы - для любых i,j считается сумма всех элементов в прямоугольнике 0,0 - i,j (на С/С++ я бы мог изобразить, на Java только читать умею :)). Все. Дальше для любого прямоугольника i,j - k,l сумма его элементов считается за O(1) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это выглядит на C++ (как уже говорил, Java только читаю):

```
const int N = 10;
const int M = 2;

int A[N][N];
int S[N][N];

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cout << (A[i][j] = rand()%10) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    S[0][0] = A[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        S[0][i] = S[0][i-1] + A[0][i];
    for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        S[i][0] = S[i-1][0] + A[i][0];

    for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        for(int j = 1; j < N; ++j)
            S[i][j] = A[i][j] + S[i-1][j] + S[i][j-1] - S[i-1][j-1];

    // Пример для крайнего справа внизу

    cout << S[N-1][N-1] - S[N-M-1][N-1] - S[N-1][N-M-1] + S[N-M-1][N-M-1] << endl;

}
```